# Using NLP or Spacy, How can we extract contextual data from a text given entity as the input?

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

For example, there is a text given (in the form of a document) along with person name "John". We need to extract all sentences from the text where there is a mention of John by his name or otherwise.

Comment: what have you already tried? this seems a pretty straightforward task.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. I am trying the entity extraction and on that basis, relation extraction but unlike simple extraction from unstructured data like city in a state, I am looking at a way to extract the whole sentence or paragraph where entity is present with direct or indirect mention.

Comment: ok, and what have you coded already?

Comment: it seems that beside `entity extraction`, you need to do `dependency parsing` to get instances that your entity was referenced without explicitly being mentioned. to @DavidBatista point, show us what you have coded already and an input text, in order to be able to help

Answer (score 0):

did you use NLTK to extract entities ?
I have done a similar one below,

```
import nltk
import re
from nltk.sem import extract_rels,rtuple
from nltk.chunk import tree2conlltags

sample = """"Michael Joseph Jackson was born in Gary, Indiana, near Chicago, on August 29, 1958.
He was the eighth of ten children in the Jackson family, a working-class African-American family living in a two-bedroom house on Jackson Street.
His mother, Katherine Esther Jackson (née Scruse), left the Baptist tradition in 1963 to become a devout Jehovah's Witness.She played clarinet and piano and had aspired to be a country-and-western performer; she worked part-time at Sears to support the family.
His father, Joseph Walter 'Joe' Jackson, a former boxer, was a steelworker at U.S. Steel.
Joe played guitar with a local rhythm and blues band, the Falcons, to supplement the family's income.
Despite being a convinced Lutheran, Joe followed his wife's faith, as did all their children.
His father's great-grandfather, July 'Jack' Gale, was a Native American medicine man and US Army scout.
Michael grew up with three sisters (Rebbie, La Toya, and Janet) and five brothers (Jackie, Tito, Jermaine, Marlon, and Randy).
A sixth brother, Marlon's twin Brandon, died shortly after birth."""

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(sample)
tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]


for i, sent in enumerate(tagged_sentences):
    sent = nltk.ne_chunk(sent) 
    print(sent)
```

This prints the below,
(S
  `/`
  (PERSON Michael/NNP Joseph/NNP Jackson/NNP)
  was/VBD
  born/VBN
  in/IN
  (GPE Gary/NNP)
  ,/,
  (GPE Indiana/NNP)
  ,/,
  near/IN
  (GPE Chicago/NNP)
  ,/,
  on/IN
  August/NNP
  29/CD
  ,/,
  1958/CD